# swapExactTokensForTokens ignore amountOutMin parameter

Tags: bsc, pancakeswap, swaps

In the token swap I am receiving less amount of the output token than that indicated in the parameter "amountOutMin". This is expected, because the token that I am swaping has a tax of 9%. What is not expected is that the transaction occurs. The transaction had to fail with "INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT". Since I am receiving less amount of tokens than the one indicated in the parameter "amountOutMin".

The token has 18 decimals (https://bscscan.com/token/0xf7469bad4e3da85b15b02a0dcfadb2c2d219a4b7)

Transaction: https://bscscan.com/tx/0xf8c1af25b432892f7c87ce57beacb938300ce7d6563cf17574ad8ec5e091ab85

Received: 3271.126023249240379059 tokens

amountOutMinParam: 3594640386952184892933 (18 decimal: 3594.640386952184892933)

The transaction has occurred even when the amount of output is less than amountOutMin. It seems that there is something important that I am not understanding.

[image: amountOutMin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AMM is only checking that it is **sending** you the `amountOutMin`, not that you are receiving it. In other words, it calls a `transfer` for that token for an amount greater than or equal `amountOutMin`.

However, **after** the transfer is called by the AMM (from the pair to your address), the token contract burns the 9% tax you are mentioning. This is not captured by the AMM.

If you want the transaction to revert if the amount received is less than `amountOutMin`, you can use the function `swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferToken` function (and other similarly named functions) instead.